# ExtJS 3 -- Always Show menu icon in GridPanel Column Header?

Tags: extjs3, gridpanel

I have a requirement to always show the menu icon in a a GridPanel's column header.  See attached image.  I've tracked down the css class and see the `<td />` tag is assigned the `x-grid3-hd-btn` on hover.  The `x-grid3-hd-btn` class uses a background image, `grid3-hd-btn.gif` to display the drop-down arrow I want, but I'm not css savvy enough to figure out how to always show it.

[image]

There doesn't seem to be a hook in the GridPanel class api's to always display this, wish there was.  Also, note that I only want the arrow icon to show, I don't want the column header to change color, etc.

Does anyone have any guidance on this?

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your stylesheet, this overwrites default extjs theme styles

```
/**
 * EXTJS Grid-3 Always visible header buttons
 */

.x-grid3-hd-btn {
display: block !important;
height: 22px !important;
}

.x-grid3-hd {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: this works fine but the menu is displayed for the columns where menuDisabled:true. How to over come this problem?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replacing the css class background image in your ext-all.css file?

original:

```
.x-grid3-header{
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    background-image:url(../images/default/grid/grid3-hrow.gif);
}
```

replace to :

```
.x-grid3-header{
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    background-image:url(../images/default/grid/grid3-hrow-over.gif);
}
```

tell me if that did it...

Comment: you could also override it in your own CSS file if you do not wish to change the framework file. ( I think it will be better practice if you leave the original file as is)

Comment: Garr.  I tried your recommendation, but it only served to change the bar, not showing the drop-down arrow (fyi, i'm using the "gray" theme.).  The arrow seems to be its own element within the header.  I'm sure if I played around and found the right css selector, i could apply the arrow at all times using your suggestion.  Thanks for the input, regardless!